# Can't retrieve PDO results outside of function

Tags: php, function, pdo

Probably the product of lack of sleep but I just can't figure this out, I've been experimenting and searching for far too long at this point so figured all I could do now is ask for help.

I have many pages that use data from a database and to condense the code a little I wanted to contain the database pulls within a function:

```
function dbh($sql, $arr){
    global $dbh;
    $stm = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stm->execute($arr);
    $row = $stm->fetch();
    return $row;
}
```

But it just won't return anything for me. The function is called on the page like so:

```
 $row = dbh('SELECT * FROM ' . $pfx . '_user WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1', array($vld_fgt));


$usr = $row['user_id'];
$sup = $row['sign_up'];
$eml = $row['email'];

echo $usr;
```

I've tried many different things but just can not get it to work. Is this possible, and if so, how do I get it to give me the results so I can use them outside of the function?

Comment: How are you handling errors? Is `$pfx` set? Are you setting `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` somewhere to ensure you get an associative array?

Comment: The function seems simple, I think the problem would be on the mysql side. Normally when I face this situation: I output `$stm->queryString`, also Try to form a raw string (with the values that would be bind) and run it from Mysql Workbench or similar, if it was something in the sql sentence you will see it there, also try to `print_r($stm->errorInfo())` It will give you some info if there's an error there.

Comment: $pfx is set in the same document as $dbh and I have had no problems with passing them through. Even with PDO::FETCH_ASSOC set I still do not get any results. In terms of error handling I have a try/catch on $dbh. I know that the function is receiving the data from the array as I've successfully printed it out within the function, my only guess is that the execute is not working but I don't know how to figure it out.

Comment: I just had `print_r($stm->errorInfo())` output `Array ( [0] => 00000 )`. `$stm->queryString` output `SELECT * FROM rightpfx_user WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1` so it looks like the array isn't binding to the query? Not sure what to do to persuade it to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is LIMIT / OFFSET which requires an integer.

By default [**Manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php) ($db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true); ) binds a parameter as a string value.

There are 2 solutions

Set

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

Or

```
$stm->bindValue(1, $$vld_fgt, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```